# How to create a thread in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1.1

Can I create a class that inherited from thread class in c#, for my Windows Phone application.

For example : 
  if my class name is 'MyClass' I want to start the thread as `new MyClass().Start();`

Like in following Java example

```
public class TagIndexer 
{
    private static class Task 
    {
        private String docId;
        private String tags;
        private String extension;

        public Task(String docId, String tags, String extension) 
        {
            this.docId = docId;
            this.tags = tags;
            this.extension = extension;
        }
    }

    private static final LinkedList<Task> queue = new LinkedList<Task>();
    private static boolean isWorking = false;

    private static class TaskRunner extends Thread 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                Task task;
                synchronized (queue) 
                {
                    task = queue.poll();
                    if (null == task) 
                    {
                        isWorking = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    isWorking = true;
                }
                /*
                 * PROCESSING CODE
                 */
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addDocument(int docId, String tags, String extension) 
    {
        Task task = new Task(Integer.toString(docId), tags, extension);

        synchronized (queue) 
        {
            queue.add(task);
            if (!isWorking) 
            {
                new TaskRunner().start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In .NET the Thread class is sealed, so no, you cannot create a class that inherits from Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new MyClazz().Start();
```

-

```
public abstract class MyThread
{
    public abstract void Run();

    public void Start()
    {
        new Thread(Run).Start();
    }
}

public class MyClazz : MyThread
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone, `Thread` is a sealed class, therefore you cannot inherit from it. If you want to keep the task-based approach, you can just create a class that will wrap a thread instance. Something like:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    protected Thread InternalThread { get; set; }

    protected abstract void Run();

    public void Start()
    {
        this.InternalThread = new Thread(this.Run);
        this.InternalThread.Start();    
    }
}
```

Of course, it's just an example. You would have to add some synchronization mechanism to prevent the `Start` method from creating multiple threads if called more than once.

Then you can inherit it to create custom tasks:

```
public class MyTask : Task
{
    protected override void Run()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this article about [`BackgroundAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundagent%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from **`MSDN`**:

- [Background Agents Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)